# Define multiple C++ class member function

Tags: c++, class

```cpp
class myclass {
public:
    myclass();
    myclass(int);
    void func();
    ~myclass();
};
```

What I am currently doing is like:

```cpp
myclass::myclass() {
    cout << "Default Constructor";
}
myclass::myclass(int a) {
    cout << "Normal Constructor";
}
void myclass::func(){
    cout<< "function f";
}
```

But every definition needs `myclass::`, which seems messy.

Can I do something like:

```
myclass::{
    myclass(){...}
    myclass(int a){...}
    void f(){...}
}
```

Gathering all the member functions under the same class and define them together?

Comment: No, you can't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: No you cannot define them in that way. You can only do that with namespaces.

Comment: You can avoid specifying the class name by defining the constructor / method / destructor bodies inline in the header.  If you define them separately, however, then the class name is required.

Comment: It may just be habit, but I honestly don't see why it's bothersome. Perhaps you actual code looks different somehow? And that makes the need to qualify the functions worse?

Comment: I would find your proposal more bothersome. For me an average class has 500 to 1 thousand code lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do something like: ... Gathering all the member functions under the same class and define them together?

Not when defining the functions outside the class definition. Repeating the class name for each member function is necessary in that case.